# Any API available for adding task to Planner app in Microsoft Teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

I'm building a chatbot with nodejs with botframework v4 and i was wondering whether their is any api etc available that would let me add a task to the Planner app in Teams.

Details-I'm building an app which would take a feedback after a certain intent. Once the feedback is filled by the user. I want the feedback/message to be automatically added to the Planner app in my Teamschannel. Is there any existing API that would let me connect from my bot to the planner in Teams?

If not,Earlier i was able to take this feedback and send it into Teamschannel as a proactive message (with sendActivity by storing the channels conversationId, tenantId).
Could I create an app where this proactive message would be taken up automatically when it comes to the channel and added to task's of the Planner?

Comment: The first step is to find out if the planner app has an API. If not, you might find it uses some other back end technology that has an API that you can use. This also sounds like something that might be achievable in an Azure Logic App

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to use the Microsoft Graph API from within your Teams app. In particular, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) how to create a Planner task.

You might need to deal with authentication in your bot though, to get access to the Graph API, if you want to act on behalf on a user (delegated access). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp) for info on that.

Comment: Thanks as mentioned in the docs when i implement the logic . const client= Client.init(token) and when i call await client.api() i get an error ReferenceError: client is not defined. Not sure what that really means..any idea?

Comment: I can't really help on the node side as I mostly use C#, but this sounds like a pretty straightforward node/Graph Api question, perhaps ask it as a separate question here on the site?

Comment: I just had one more question as mentioned in as answer since i couldnt post picture here.